# How to select one symbol in CLion?

Tags: c++, windows, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm new in CLion, I install newest version of it (v3.4) from official website.

I spent about 2 hours because faced with very strange error:
"Left with selection" shortcut defined to <kbd>Shift + Left</kbd> in settings, but when I press <kbd>Shift + Left</kbd> I "jump" to previous word, such as I press <kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd>.

I think it is very strange and I really have no variants how to deal with it.

The same with "Right with selection", which defined to <kbd>Shift + Right</kbd> but works as <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd>.

[image: "Left with Selection" in my CLion settings]

[image: "Right with Selection" in my CLion settings]

I really will be happy if someone helps me.

P.S. I work under Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: 1) Please use `Search by shortcut` action (icon next to search field) and see what other actions have such `Shift + Left/Right` assigned to them. 2) Try with original Default keymap 3) Disable any custom plugins (that are not installed by default).

Comment: SOLVED! It is just IdeaVim plugin was enabled! I disable it and issue was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest CLION is the 2017.1 RC.

The shift + arrow works for me in both win10 and ubuntu 16.04

Does shift and control keys work properly in other applications? Maybe restart your PC and your wireless keyboard if you have one?

Comment: Thank you, @nikferrari !
I have restarted my laptop but it has no results. I use built-in keyboard.
Also, when my CLion just opened, caret stay in "insert" mode...
And when caret in the end of line, I can't move to the next line via "Right arrow" button.

Comment: If you think that your problem is reproducible somehow you can always report it to their bug tracking site https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP. I suspect that is a JVM issue with windows 8.